# Cannot apply custom css to IE in the theme

Tags: themes, css, browser-compatibility

For the twentythirteen, twentyfourteen or any theme made by Wordpress, editing `ie.css` which is in `themefolder\css\ie.css` doesn't result in any changes in Internet Explorer. I'm actually using IE11, but whatever I change the document mode or the user agent to, it's still not resulting to any changes.

I also noticed Wordpress injects `ie` class to the `<html>` tag when browsing from IE. So, I applied such CSS codes: `.ie body { display: none !important; padding: 100px; }`, but still no results.

Comment: Is `ie.css` loaded?

Comment: Yes, within <!--[if lt IE 9]> condition, and I'm using IE 11 with document mode and user agent as IE 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like TwentyFourteen includes the ie.css stylesheet within a '**less than IE 9**' conditional tag, which would explain why it's not working for IE11.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-ie-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_answers/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/css/ie.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
```

Sounds like you'll want to enqueue your own IE specific stylesheet. This is probably done cleanest from within a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so you can update 2014 when possible.

**You can use this code to enqueue your own IE specific stylesheet:**

```
// Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-ie-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my_ie_styles.css', array( 'twentyfourteen-style', 'genericons' ), '20131205' );
wp_style_add_data( 'my-ie-styles', 'conditional', 'IE' );
```

`wp_style_add_data()` will output the link tag within an IE specific conditional:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-ie-styles-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress_answers/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/css/my_ie_styles.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Weird, the changes are only applied when the document mode (from the developer options) is 9.

Comment: @AhmedSaad Looks like [MS dropped conditions comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/) as of IE10. You may want to consider using Modernizr feature detection rather than using IE specific conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional stylesheet for IE is only loaded for IE6, 7 and 8 in the wordpress default themes. For every version after IE8, the theme's default stylesheet is loaded. You can add body classes for IE and then style your theme according to that